# Foreign keys in entity framework 4.1

Tags: .net, data-annotations, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am working on Entity Framework 4.1 and using data annotations for foreign keys. I want to know how can we define one to many relationship between product and categories. I want to map category. categoryId with product.cid

```
public class Category
{
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Both these approaches should work:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public string CId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Or:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

`ForeignKeyAttribute` is used to pair navigation property and foreign key property. It contains either the name of related navigation property or the name of related foreign key property.

Comment: @Ladislave Will it not be [ForeignKey("CategoryId")] inside Product ?

Comment: @Anyone Can someone explain to me if there are any differences between these two approaches? They seem identical but is there anything that might cause a developer choose one method over the other?

Answer (score 6):

You use entityconfigurations for this.

In the entityconfiguration, add this mapping to the category entityconfiguration:

```
HasMany<Product>(x => x.Products).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(x => x.CId);
```

You only need to map it on one of your classes and DbContext is clever enough to use it.

See this [blog post](http://stuartgatenby.com/ef/2011/03/05/entity-framework-relationship-mapping-best-of-both-worlds-ef4-1ctp5-code-only-fluent-api/) for more info.

**EDIT** To do this using data annotations I believe the correct approach is as follows:

```
[RelatedTo(RelatedProperty="Products", Key="CId", RelatedKey="CategoryId")]
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

Comment: @Gates: I want to do it using data annotations

Comment: @Gates How can I do this using data annotaions instead of fluent API

Comment: I think that's it. Haven't used annotations for this since CTP4 which is 1 version back, but I'm pretty sure that's right.