# What's the Entity Framework equivalent of NHibernate's References(x => x.ResidenceCountry).Column("ResidingInCountryId")?

Tags: entity-framework, mapping

I have this code:

```
class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}


class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public int ResidingInCountryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country ResidenceCountry { get; set; }
}
```

What should I put on OnModelCreating? So I can navigate the Country's CountryName from Employee

Comment: Are you using EF 4.1 with code first?

Comment: yeah, I'm using EF 4.1 with code first. I updated my question. I think `virtual Country ResidenceCountry` need manual mapping. The actual backing database field of `ResidenceCountry` property is ResidingInCountryId

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope it helps. I'm still learning this stuff myself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quoting directly from [this blog posting](http://ianfnelson.com/blog/entityframeworkadventure2/) by [Ian Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2084/ian-nelson), but I think this is what you need:

---

Here's how you’d rename a foreign key on a unidirectional one-to-many relationship in Fluent NHibernate:

```
References(x => x.AudioFormat).Column("AudioFormat");
```

Whilst in Entity Framework code-first, the equivalent is:

```
HasOptional(x => x.AudioFormat)  
    .WithMany()   
    .IsIndependent()   
    .Map(m => m.MapKey(a => a.Id, "AudioFormat"));
```

Comment: There's no more IsIndependent method on EF 4.1. I'm able to solve my problem using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448979/foreign-keys-in-entity-framework-4-1/5449047#5449047 But then EF's POCO is not plain anymore :-)  I prefer the second approach(the Foreign key is on class, not on primitive type)