# Nullable Properties in EF Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, nullable

I hope everyone remembers the Northwind database. As it has an Employee table which has a self-reference to itself. The Foreign Key is named 'ReportTo' or something like that which in turn is a Nullable field.

I am trying to implement such a table for a project in hand using EF Code First plus MVC3. The scenario is that: There is a Man class from which the User is derived. The mentioned field 'ReportTo' is set on the latter class (User). Here is the POCO:

```
[LocalizedAttribute("ReportTo")]
    public long ReportsTo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ReportsTo")]
    public virtual IList<User> ReportsChild { get; set; }
```

*But EF generated this field as 'Not Null' in the Database.* I have tried to use `?` exactly after `IList<User>`, which looks like `IList<User>?` that generates an error. I have also tried to define it as fluent API as:

`modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(s => s.ReportsChild).IsOptional();`

But both above ways give me this error:

> The type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

I've surfed the web but I could just find similar solutions as what I've done already.

What might be the reason?
If I change `IList<User>` into `User`, would it still work correctly as the Foreign key?
How can I get ride of this error?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public long? ReportsTo { get; set; }`?  Isn't that the one you're trying to fix?

Comment: Reference types like `IList<User>` are already nullable. You only need the `?` for non-reference types to indicate you want to use the new .NET wrapper which supports making them null. `long?` is the same as `Nullable<long>` or `Nullable<Int64>`.

Comment: Yes that is the one. But as far as I know it should be a reference type as the name of an entity or else how EF may understand which entities should relate to each other?

Comment: As an aside, it's commonplace to use `ICollection<T>` rather than `IList<T>` for nagivation properties that reference to a set of related entities.

Comment: @Yuck: Yes the reference types are supposed to be so.. But as the database was generated the field formed as Not Null! And I'm not able to insert any record since getting another crazy error: 'Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.'

Comment: If you want add all class in your question, and I write all relationship what you want))

Comment: O.. my friend I didn't really mean like that! Anyway thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must wrirte as follow

```
 public Nullable<long> ReportsTo { get; set; }
```

**EDIT**

```
public long? ReportsTo { get; set; }
```

Comment: Yes.. It works well for me.. I had to make the foreign key as nullable not the reference type.. Thanks

Comment: Not at all. Please add voice to my answer for my reputations)))

Answer (score 1):

You are actually doing a one-many relationship. Which means that it's the `User` who **has** the foreign key.

There are two ways to solve this.

- Transfer that to the `User` entity. And get rid of the IList. Just use the type of whatever entity that is. (Employee?) Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448979/foreign-keys-in-entity-framework-4-1)

Or

- Get rid of below: because EF should automatically map that for you. The `User` table will automatically create a FK column of that entity's ID which is a one (that entity) to many (`User`) relationship.

  `[LocalizedAttribute("ReportTo")]
    public long ReportsTo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ReportsTo")]`

Comment: Np. Vote up at least if you dont find this as an answer.