# Self-referencing ordered relationships in entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Bear with me - I'm not quite sure how to explain this...

I have an 'item' base class, in this case imagine it to be a task. A given task can have sub tasks (multiple children), and a child task can have multiple parents.

E.g. I might have a task called "buy canned tuna", this could appear as a sub-task of "shopping" and also "today's tasks".

So far so good, but the kicker is that I want the child tasks to be ordered. I cannot see how to do this in EF. I've started working on the notion of an OrderedItem class but I can't get this to work in EF.

**Edit:**

The ordering needs to be arbitrary for each parent-child join. This means that the same item will have a different order per parent. For example, buying tuna might be my number one priority for today, but number 11 on my shopping list.

Any ideas on the best approach?

```
Public MustInherit Class ItemBase
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Overridable Property Parents As ICollection(Of OrderedItem)
    Public Overridable Property Children As ICollection(Of OrderedItem)
End Class

Public Class OrderedItem
    <Key(), Column(Order:=0)> _
    Public Property ParentID As Integer
    <Key(), Column(Order:=1)> _
    Public Property ItemID As Integer
    Public Property Parent As ItemBase
    Public Property Item As ItemBase
    Public Property Order As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: ordered - how? by order of creation?

Comment: The order will be arbitrary, and is on a per-parent basis. So buying tuna might be my number one priority for today, but number 11 on my shopping list.

Comment: well if so you need to add a priority to each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your edit - you seem to be doing quite well, using a join table with additional `Order` field would seem to be the best approach.

Note though that the OrderedItem's `ParentId` and `ItemId` aren't *keys* (so no need for the `Key` attribute), they are *foreign keys*, referencing the entity table. EF will normally figure out foreign keys on its own from the navigation properties, but when it comes to recognizing the integer properties (`ItemID`, etc), you can give it a hint using the `ForeignKey("...")` attribute (see this answer: [Foreign keys in entity framework 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448979/foreign-keys-in-entity-framework-4-1))

Also note that a better name for `OrderedItem` would be `ItemChildItemOrder` or something, since it doesn't represent a business entity but a join table entry.

Edit 2: The usage would be `item.Children.OrderBy(Function(child) child.Order).ToList()`

Comment: See the comment above - the order will be arbitrary

Comment: I've used the Key annotation to use the two ids as a compound key, rather than adding an unnecessary ID column. If I add the foreign key annotations, the migration adds fields ParentID, ItemID, ItemBase_ID and ItemBase_ID2. How can I tell EF that the parent and item id's are to be used for this relationship?

Comment: @JimmyP, I see. Then what issues do you have? "I can't get this to work in EF." isn't terribly clear to me.

Comment: @JimmyP, why are you using an ItemBase abstract class at all, instead of just Item? I don't see inheritance being of any use here.

Comment: I've not posted the subclasses here for brevity. Comfortable that it's the right approach for this problem.

Comment: Ok, so back to the problem: it looks like this intermediate table is the correct approach. How can I get EF to use my ParentID and ItemID fields to hold the relationship between these objects, rather than creating it's own columns?

Comment: @JimmyP, perhaps you're not using the ForeignKey attributes properly, or perhaps EF is being difficult. Have you tried letting it guess based on the names (i.e. without an attribute)? If neither of the two approaches work, you might want to use the Fluent API to set up the relationships.

Comment: @JimmyP, in C# syntax, the Fluent API approach would be `model.Entity<OrderedItem>().HasRequired(oi => oi.Parent).WithMany(p => p.Children).HasForeignKey(oi => oi.ParentId)`, in the DbContext's OnModelBuilding event (same for `oi.Item`)

Comment: That's it! Perfect, thanks. I've just appended a WillCascadeOnDelete(False) to get the migration to run.