# Foreign Keys or virtual fields

Tags: model-view-controller, foreign-key-relationship

I have a Project table with some fields that point to a Participant table but all with a different meaning of course:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace iMaSys.Models
{
    public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(128)]
        [Display(Name = "Omschrijving")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Startdatum")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Einddatum")]
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

        public Boolean Active { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Mediation Casenummer")]
        public string Mediation_casenr { get; set; }



        public  Participant CaseManager { get; set; }
        public  Participant Supervisor { get; set; }
        public  Participant Party_1 { get; set; }
        public  Participant Party_2 { get; set; }
        public  Participant Client { get; set; }
        public  Participant InterventionManager { get; set; }
        public  Participant Mediator { get; set; }

        public virtual ProjectCategorySub ProjectCategorySubject { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

The fields Casemanager, Supervisor, Party_1 etc all point to Participant. In Particpant I added InverseProperties to tell the framework the connection between Projects and Participants:

```
[InverseProperty("Mediator")]
public List<Project> ProjectMediators { get; set; }

[InverseProperty("Supervisor")]
public List<Project> ProjectSupervisors { get; set; }
etc. etc.
```

After add-migration and update-database the fields in Project are named like:

CaseManager_ParticipantID etc. I just simply need CaseManagerID to point to Participant_ParticipantID. I tried several things but I seem not to understand howto get it to work.

I'm stuck on this one, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Best regards, Janno Hordijk

Comment: perhaps [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448979/foreign-keys-in-entity-framework-4-1)

Comment: I updated my question to include the InverseProperties. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself but want to share what I found out.

At Participant:

```
    [InverseProperty("Mediator")]
    public virtual ICollection<Project> MediatorProjects { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Supervisor")]
    public virtual ICollection<Project> SupervisorProjects { get; set; }
```

At Project:

```
    [ForeignKey("Mediator")]
    public int? Mediator_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Participant Mediator { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Supervisor")]
    public int? Supervisor_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Participant Supervisor { get; set; }
```

Now the database is ok and my fieldnames are Supervisor_ID instead of Supervisor_Participant_ID

Best regards, Janno