# Entity Framework Foreign Key customization

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I am using Entity Framework 6.0, I know the purpose of FK, what I need is a little bit tweaking on it.

This is example code snippet

```
class CommonMaster
{
      public int ID {get;set;}
      public string Name {get;set;}
      public string Value {get;set;}
      public string Type {get;set;}
}

class BankDetails
{
  //all relevant fields
  public int CustomerType {get;set;}  //expected by ef

  public string CustomerType {get;set;} //the one i want
  [ForeignKey("CustomerType")] //expected by ef
  public virtual CommonMaster CommonMaster_CustomerType {get;set;}
}
```

Here by default the join will be

```
from BankDetails bd join CommonMaster cm on bd.CustomerType = cm.Value
```

Here by default ef queries

```
[table1_fk] = [table2_pk]
```

What I want is

```
[table1_somefield with codevalue]= [table2 _ code value]
```

If it isn't possible, can you please provide a best alternative to achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreign keys in entity framework 4.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448979/foreign-keys-in-entity-framework-4-1)

Answer (score 0):

It depend on what strategy you want to use. For Code First it could be done like this.
[Foreign key EF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5449047/2313116)